# Send external file without readfile() PHP

Tags: php, file, gateway

How can i give file from another server when user open's my site link? Without using function like readfile and another functions to redirect traffic. Is it possible to give file without downloading it to my server?

For example:

1. User open's link `http://mysite.com/download.php`
2. My server gives him a file from 'https://googledrive.com/host/0B...' with name `file.exe` without downloading it to my server

So for user it's like he downloaded file `file.exe` from `mysite.com` but really it's from googledrive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `header('Location: ..')` to redirect them to the download URL, you can't download files from another server unless you have FTP access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when i use `header('Location: 'https://googledrive.com/host/0BF2332Fd')` downloaded file has  name `0BF2332Fd` how can i change it to `file.exe`?

Comment: You can't, the download headers are sent by Google and can't be edited by you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to modify the file name that is shown but not want to download it to the server. Well that is not possible.

You have to download the file from the location to provide it to the client when you plan on modify any meta information like the filename or similar.

The filename is a HTTP property which is sent by the server (in your case google drive). In the moment you want to modify it the http trafic has to be intercepted by your server means that the content has to go through your server (if you store the file or not is another thing.

HTTP is not like FTP. In FTP the data stream is separated. In HTTP on the other hand is everything in one stream (file information + content).

You can handle All or nothing.